dbt error that selection does not match any enabled nodes
I new to DBT and just starting learning it. I was following a Ytube example and getting error while running a .sql file.
I am running below command but getting error, can someone help how to run this specific file and why salestarget is issuing a warning -
dbt run -m storeperformance.sql
Error -
20:35:48  Running with dbt=1.8.0
20:35:49  Registered adapter: snowflake=1.8.3
20:35:50  [WARNING]: Configuration paths exist in your dbt_project.yml file which do not apply to any resources.
There are 1 unused configuration paths:
models.oms_dbt_proj.example.salestarget
20:35:50  Found 9 models, 1 seed, 4 data tests, 449 macros
20:35:50  The selection criterion 'storeperformance.sql' does not match any enabled nodes
20:35:50
20:35:50  Nothing to do. Try checking your model configs and model specification args


